# Not Getting The Full Upload Speed On OpenVPN

Tags: openvpn

OK so my upload and download speed at home is 1gbps i installed openvpn on a ovh server that is also 1gbps up and down, both the server and i are in the uk london and i am using ASUS RT-AC5300 AiMesh Tri-band 4 x 4 Gigabit Wireless Gaming Router when i turn the openvpn on my router i get a max upload and download speed of 30mbps is there something in my setting or something i can add to my setting to make it go faster

i have searched the whole internet some people having the same issue but there seems to be no answers to fix it

Here Is My Config Minus The Certificate

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
sndbuf 0
rcvbuf 0
remote MYIP 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
auth SHA512
cipher AES-256-CBC
setenv opt block-outside-dns
key-direction 1
verb 3
```

Server Config File

```
  port 1194
    proto udp
    dev tun
    sndbuf 0
    rcvbuf 0
    ca ca.crt
    cert server.crt
    key server.key
    dh dh.pem
    auth SHA512
    tls-auth ta.key 0
    topology subnet
    server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
    ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
    push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
    push "dhcp-option DNS 127.0.0.1"
    push "dhcp-option DNS 213.186.33.99"
    keepalive 10 120
    cipher AES-256-CBC
    user nobody
    group nogroup
    persist-key
    persist-tun
    status openvpn-status.log
    verb 3
    crl-verify crl.pem
```

Things I Have Tried
1) changing port
2)sndbuf 0
  rcvbuf 0

Answer (score 0):

Figured out it was my router not being able to handle it even though this is to top of the range router.